# AMPL constraint syntax

Tags: constraints, linear-programming, ampl

I am working on a project for a computational optimization class and am having a problem writing a particular constraint for my mixed integer program.

The project is essentially a loan portfolio optimization problem where I am trying to maximize an impact on poverty while satisfying constraints on risk, return and disbursement.  I have almost all my constraints working as intended but its the last one that is giving me an issue.

Here are the sets;

```
#SETS
set REGION;                                 #Set of regions
set COUNTRY;                                #Set of countries
set LOAN_DURATION;                          #Set of loans
set GROUP within {COUNTRY,REGION};          #Set of countries within regions
```

Decision Variables

```
#VARIABLES

var x{COUNTRY,LOAN_DURATION}>=0;            #Amount of money that can be loaned     #to each country c by loan type l
var y{COUNTRY,LOAN_DURATION} binary;        #decision of whether to use loan type #l for each country c
```

And here is the constraint that is giving me an issue;

```
subject to WITHIN_REGION{r in REGION, (c,r) in GROUP, l in LOAN_DURATION}:
x[c,l] <= QUOTA[r]*sum{c in COUNTRY, l in LOAN_DURATION} x[c,l];
```

What I am trying to do is say that for each region, check the amount of money loaned to each country and make sure that it is less than or equal to half of the quota loaned out to that region. When I try to run this model I just get a basic syntax error for the second line.

I have a similar constraint before this one which checks to make sure each region at least gets its region quota of the total amount loaned, and it seems to be working as intended;

```
subject to REGION_QUOTA{r in REGION}:
sum{(c,r) in GROUP, l in LOAN_DURATION} x[c,l] >= QUOTA[r]*sum{c in COUNTRY, l in LOAN_DURATION} x[c,l];
```

So I was wondering if there were any ampl experts out there that could give me a hand getting this last constraint to work.

Thanks

Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use the same index `c` name in two different indexing expressions with overlapping scope, `(c,r) in GROUP` and `c in COUNTRY`. You can rename the second index to avoid the error:

```
subject to WITHIN_REGION{r in REGION, (c,r) in GROUP, l in LOAN_DURATION}:
x[c,l] <= QUOTA[r]*sum{c2 in COUNTRY, l in LOAN_DURATION} x[c2,l];
```

although if you want to sum `x[c2,l]` over all countries in region `r`, which seems to be the case, you should probably have something like:

```
subject to WITHIN_REGION{r in REGION, (c,r) in GROUP, l in LOAN_DURATION}:
x[c,l] <= QUOTA[r]*sum{(c2,r) in GROUP, l in LOAN_DURATION} x[c2,l];
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.  When I applied your suggestion to c, and l, it worked as intended.

Comment: Right, I didn't notice that `l` also needs renaming.